# Is it possible to profile only certain packages using GHC's profiler?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is it possible to only generate cost-centres for functions defined in certain packages? I'm not sure if this question actually makes sense from a technical viewpoint, in that case please enlighten me. What I'm interested in, essentially, is to get profiler output that only shows cost-centres for bindings in my own packages. Is this possible?

Alternatively I'd like to be able exclude cost-centres from some packages. Is this possible?

Comment: I think it's not possible, but it could be quite useful!

Comment: I believe *all* the files you're linking together have to be built in profiling mode. However, that says nothing about whether you can define the cost centers the way you want or not...

Comment: Maybe my question is inaccurate. In my profiling output I see output from some packages (e.g. from `vector`) but I can't see any cost centers from e.g. `containers`.